# Format dates based on date precision

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I am using Wikidata Query Service to get the dates of population of some places. The output gives a raw result in the format `2010-01-01T00:00:00Z` (as an example). I have also retrieved the date precision of each date. The [query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%0A%20%20%3Fplace%0A%20%20%3FplaceLabel%0A%20%20%3Fpopulation%0A%20%20%3FpopulationDate%0A%20%20%3FpopulationDatePrecision%0A%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fplace%20p%3AP31%20%3FinstanceOf.%0A%20%20%3FinstanceOf%20ps%3AP31%2Fwdt%3A279%2A%20wd%3AQ134390.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%20p%3AP1082%20%3Fpop_statement%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fpop_statement%20ps%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20pqv%3AP585%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3AtimePrecision%20%3FpopulationDatePrecision%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3AtimeValue%20%3FpopulationDate%20%5D.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20minus%20%7B%20%3FinstanceOf%20pq%3AP582%20%3FendTime.%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20service%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3FplaceLabel%0A) results display the dates in `1 January 2010` format, but upon downloading the csv or tsv file, the dates are still displayed in the raw format `2010-01-01T00:00:00Z`.

I would want to display the following dates based on their date precision:

if (date precision = `11`), display `1 January 2010`
if (date precision = `10`), display `January 2010`
if (date precision = `9`), display `2010`
otherwise, just display the raw date

How can I do this, and how can I force the downloaded csv or tsv file to display the formatted dates?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ?place
  ?placeLabel
  ?population
  ?populationDate
  ?populationDatePrecision

WHERE {
  ?place p:P31 ?instanceOf.
  ?instanceOf ps:P31/wdt:279* wd:Q134390.
  
  OPTIONAL {
    ?place p:P1082 ?pop_statement .
    ?pop_statement ps:P1082 ?population;
      pqv:P585 [
                wikibase:timePrecision ?populationDatePrecision;
                wikibase:timeValue ?populationDate ].
  }
  
  minus { ?instanceOf pq:P582 ?endTime. }
  
  service wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
} ORDER BY ?placeLabel
```

Comment: It looks like the client does some post-processing.
In fact, if you look at the raw string (https://w.wiki/4yLM), even in SPARQL you get the unformatted output.
This is confirmed here:
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Dates#Precision

Comment: You might still use `BIND` and `CONCAT` to compute the string yourself however.