# Sparql query dates json results in the same format that in web portal

Tags: sparql, wikidata, sparqlwrapper, wikidata-query-service

How to get the results related to dates from Sparql queries in wikidata in JSON through Python codes in the same format they appear when I query directly through the web?

When I query in [Wikidata Query Portal](https://w.wiki/532d) (Try it), some **dates** appear formatted like `21 de junho de 1839`, but when i request them via Python with the library SPARQLWrapper, they appear this way: `1839-06-21T00:00:00Z`. How to get the "beautified version" from site in JSON?

Comment: same question was asked some weeks ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71556196/format-dates-based-on-date-precision - short answer: what you see in the browser is just some post-processing in the client code, the raw data, and that is what SPARQL returns, is of course the datetime literal - this allows any client to use their own rendering. Indeed, you can try to create your own rendered string directly in SPARQL, but I don't see why. Once you "show" the data somewhere, it's easier to use one of the APIs then to format date literals

Comment: So is there any way to have the same browser result in json? Unfortunately I don't know how to do it. I'm starting to study SPARQL queries. Thanks

Comment: SPARQL allows to get year, month and day from a datetime literal. With BIND keyword and CONCAT you can then build your own string. Indeed, for each month number you need the corresponding month string, use VALUES keywod for this

Comment: What is beautiful is in the eyes of the spectator. For me the ISO version is a beauty compared to the localized version. It is much easier to go from ISO to localized then the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly modified your query and added it to the [wikidata.yaml](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyLoDStorage/blob/2afaf4fd834fa9f074fee744c48350f6e6bc4312/sampledata/wikidata.yaml#L129) sample queries of the [pyLodStorage](https://pypi.org/project/pylodstorage/) library for which i am committer so that

```bash
sparqlquery -qp wikidata.yaml -qn MachadoDeAssis -f github
```

works and gives the cut&paste result shown further down below.

```bash
sparqlquery -qp wikidata.yaml -qn MachadoDeAssis -f json
```

returns

```json
[
  {
    "author": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q311145",
    "authorLabel": "Machado de Assis",
    "birthDate": "1839-06-21 00:00:00"
  }
]
```

now you can pipe the result thru

```bash
| jq '.[] | .birthDate | strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") | strftime("%c")'
```

```bash
sparqlquery -qp wikidata.yaml -qn MachadoDeAssis -f json | jq '.[] | .birthDate | strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") | strftime("%c")'
```

which results in

```
"Fri Jun 21 00:00:00 1839"
```

if all runs well in a different locale the output should be according to your locale.

### MachadoDeAssis

#### query

```
# modified by WF 2022-07-22
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?author ?authorLabel ?birthDate
WHERE 
{
  VALUES ?authorLabel {
    "Machado de Assis"@pt
  }
  # Instance of Human
  ?author wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
  # Joaquim Maria Machado de Assis
  ?author rdfs:label ?authorLabel.
  FILTER (LANG(?authorLabel) = "pt").
  # birthDate
  ?author wdt:P569 ?birthDate .
}
```

[try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23%20modified%20by%20WF%202022-07-22%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A//www.wikidata.org/entity/%3E%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A//www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/%3E%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A//www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema%23%3E%0ASELECT%20%3Fauthor%20%3FauthorLabel%20%3FbirthDate%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3FauthorLabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22Machado%20de%20Assis%22%40pt%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%23%20Instance%20of%20Human%0A%20%20%3Fauthor%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%20.%0A%20%20%23%20Joaquim%20Maria%20Machado%20de%20Assis%0A%20%20%3Fauthor%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FauthorLabel.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28LANG%28%3FauthorLabel%29%20%3D%20%22pt%22%29.%0A%20%20%23%20birthDate%0A%20%20%3Fauthor%20wdt%3AP569%20%3FbirthDate%20.%0A%7D%0A)

### result

| author | authorLabel | birthDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q311145 | Machado de Assis | 1839-06-21 00:00:00 |

Comment: Thanks @Wolfgang Fahl. It helps a lot!